# Update/Refresh Listbox based on Dropdown selection with trigger("chosen:updated")

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

I have a Listbox that I need refreshed after a user selects an option in DropdownList.

[image: View of lists]

Image is self explanatory. If one selects Department -> load list of departmetns in Listbox, if one selects Vat Rate refresh/load list of vat rates into the listbox below. (Default department list is loaded on page load). I am currently attempting this with `trigger("chosen:updated")` and having no luck refreshing listbox. Here is my code for that functionality.

```
$(function () {
 $("#SelectFilter").change(function () {

    if (document.getElementById('SelectFilter').value == 1) //dropdownlist 
    {   
        //empty listbox         
        $('#SelectItems').empty();

        //append new list to listbox
        $.each(data.Departments, function (index, element) {
            $('#SelectItems').append('<option value="' + element.Value + '">'
                + element.Text + '</option>');
        });

        //refresh
        $('#SelectItems').trigger("chosen:updated");
    }     
    if (document.getElementById('SelectFilter').value == 2)
    {            
        $('#SelectItems').empty();

        $.each(data.VatRates, function (index, element) {
            $('#SelectItems').append('<option value="' + element.Value + '">'
                + element.Text + '</option>');
        });

        $('#SelectItems').trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
 });
```

});

Recognising the selected value from the dropdownlist isnt an issue, that works fine. Listbox is currently not getting updated/refresh with new selection. And I cannot figure out were I am going wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all your code for creating the list into a function, and then bind an event on chosing one of the selected items to call this function which generates a new list instead of using .trigger(). If you provide the HTML part as well, I'll post example code soon.

Comment: I am currently retrieving my list(s) from controller that returns them as JSON objects `$.getJSON('/Product/GetLists', function (data)`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you have a problem with recognizing the selected value, or with populating the secondary select tag, or with the initial loading of the data. So I am providing an example of the three steps.

First, to detect the selected value, you need to provide a `.change()` handler and extract the selected value with `.val()`. Something similar to this:

```
$("#SelectFilter").change( function() {
  var v = $(this).val();  
  if (v=="value1") {

  } else if (v=="value2") {

  } else {

  } 
});
```

then each of the changes detected has to refresh the contents of the secondary select tag, something as simple as this...

```
  $("#SelectItems").empty();
  ['first item','second item','troisième'].forEach( (v,i) => 
    $("#SelectItems").append($("<option>").val("item"+i).text(v))
  );
}
```

And finally triggering the initial load should be as simple as triggering a change event

```
$("#SelectFilter").change();
```

I have put all the steps together in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mud9u8yL/6/

Comment: recognizing the selected value isn't the issue. Tested that with alert and it works fine. Sorry I didn't make that clear. So I just need to add `$("#SelectFilter").change();` after appending new list, just to clarify?

Comment: It isn't still clear to me what your problem is, so I can't say that triggering the event is the issue. It won't hurt you try it.

Comment: goal is to refresh listbox when selection in dropdownlist is made. Listbox isnt not getting refreshed/updated with new list on click/change event of dropdown.

Comment: I just solved the problem. Was a typo on my end I had forgot to pull/get the JSON list on the dropdown change `$.getJSON('/Product/GetLists',function (data) `. Its now working as intended with the code I posted, after adding that line.